Huawei push kit integration with react-native project
I tried integrating Huawei push kit with my react-native app for ios.
But its not working.
If anybody have ever succeeded in doing so, then please share.
I tried every step provided here, as per the official documentationHms push kit for ios.
But still failed.
EDIT

Signed in to app gallery connect(Huawei)
Added my iOS app with exact app id, store id and app name
Generated APNs authentication key in App Store Connect as per https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMSCore-Guides/ios-dev-prepare-0000001062940204#section1870915174228
Enabled push kit for iOS app from app gallery connect
Added APNs authentication key, Key ID, and Team ID to iOS configuration
Downloaded agconnect-services.plist and added inside iOS folder of the project
Integrated push kit sdk

added HmsPushSdk and installed pods using pod install
 pod 'HmsPushSDK'


From Xcode

from signing and capabilities, added push notification
under background modes, selected background processing and remote notification



signing and capabilities from Xcode
trying to get device token using below code snippet but HmsPushInstanceId itself is null.
import {
    HmsPushEvent,
    HmsPushInstanceId,
    HmsPushMessaging,
    // RNRemoteMessage,
} from '@hmscore/react-native-hms-push';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

import { isDeviceInChina } from '../../globalization/utils/getCountry';

function useHuwaeiPushService({ setUserAndToken = () => {} }) {

    const activateHuwaeiPush = () => {
        HmsPushMessaging?.turnOnPush()
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('turnOnPush', result);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(`[turnOnPush] Error/Exception: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
            });
    };

    const getHuwaeiPushToken = async () => {
        console.log(
            'HmsPushInstanceId:: ',
            HmsPushInstanceId,
            HmsPushMessaging,
            HmsPushEvent,
        );
        if (!isDeviceInChina()) {
            return;
        }

        activateHuwaeiPush();

        HmsPushInstanceId?.getToken('')
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('getToken::', result);
                setUserAndToken((pv) => {
                    return {
                        ...pv,
                        messagingToken: result?.result,
                    };
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(`[getToken] Error/Exception: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
            });
    };

    return {
        getHuwaeiPushToken,
    };
}

export default useHuwaeiPushService;



@DarkBee thank you so much for the downvote.
kindly have the look at the edit
